# How to position these divs on top of each other

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I have 3 divs that only contain a background color and what I want to make is something similar to the google chrome logo.

This is just part of the code, there is more content that comes on top of all this, but this is basically the background for the page.

Right now, green is on top of red which is fine. But yellow is below both red and green and it should be on TOP of green and UNDER red div. Sort of like entangled divs.

Is there a way to put the yellow div **on top of green and under red div** to make it look more like google chrome logo.

[image: Click here to see the image of what i want it to look like]

This is the best i can explain lol i know its complex to understand what im doing.

[Here's the code](https://codepen.io/xenia-radulovi/pen/bGLVgQm) (click for codepen)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.red {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150vh;
  transform: rotate(58deg);
  background-color: #b71724;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in;
}

.green {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
  width: 110%;
  height: 150vh;
  transform: rotate(-58deg);
  background-color: #2c4b2b;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in;
}

.yellow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #d1aa3b;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-div red"></div>
  <div class="bg-div green"></div>
  <div class="bg-div yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense. if green is _over_ red, how can yellow be over green and under red? Try doing that with three playing cards. You need a different strategy.

Comment: @isherwood i edited the question and added an image to present what im looking for

Comment: Would it be possible to have two divs for yellow; one for the left half and one for the right half? Adjust the z-index of each to go over/under the neighboring div and allow them to meet in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is possible with something like paper, but z-index is more like a stack of plates. It would be like stacking plates so that the bottom one is also on top of the top one. Not going to happen.

The only way you could try to "cheat" a solution is to copy the bottom element (yellow), raise it all the way to the top, and somehow mask it so that it **looks** like it's both under red and above green. I'm not sure what you're trying to do in your actual application, but I would recommend just achieving the effect with an image.

But there is no way to make just these three divs work in the way you describe.

Comment: I really thought it was possible somehow. It seemed simple when I got the idea but now I see there is no way to achieve this. Thank you so much!

Comment: @freya21 no problem! I faced this exact same thing using ProcessingJS a long time ago, I remember feeling like the solution was so close.

Answer (score 0):

Assign differents z-index :

```
.red {
 z-index : 3;
}
.yellow {
 z-index : 2;
}
.green {
 z-index : 1;
}
```

If you put the same z-index for two divs, then their place into the HTML code will determine their position (last in the body in front)

Comment: i tried, but then the green would be in the same position as the yellow right now, which would be on the bottom of all divs. What i want to achieve is for each div to be on top of one div and under another div

Comment: You need to apply your solution to the original code to demonstrate that it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the z-index on the red and green as you used on yellow changing the z-index of yellow to 0 and defining the z-index of green to -1 and the z-index of red to 1.

Comment: i tried but still that would make one div go on top of everything and one on the bottom of everything..

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem is to use an extra div to close the position of the last div, I show you an example code:

```css
      .contain {
        position: relative;
        padding: 20px;
      }
      div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 400px;
      }
      .red {
        position: absolute;
        background: red;
        left: 220px;
        transform: rotate(-33deg);
        z-index: 2;
      }
      .yellow {
        position: absolute;
        background: yellow;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        top: 140px;
        left: 160px;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      .greenOut {
        height: 200px;
        z-index: 3;
        background: green;
        transform: rotate(34deg);
        position: absolute;
        left: 138px;
        top: 34px;
      }
      .green {
        position: absolute;
        background: green;
        transform: rotate(34deg);
        left: 80px;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="contain">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="yellow"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
      <div class="greenOut"></div>
    </div>
```